# How do I create rDNS (Reverse DNS)

Tags: centos, reverse-dns, dns-zone

How to create rDNS (Reverse DNS), I am using Centos 7.0 and I need to create rDNS for 50 IP's and domain.

Can you please guide me how can I create.

Example.

```
Example.com - xxx.xxx.xxx.xx0
Example.xyz - xxx.xxx.xxx.xx1
```

Thank in advance

Comment: where did you get the ip froms? your hoster? if so: the hoster is the one entering the RDNS in most situations.

Answer (score 1):

Create the Zone:

```
[root@ns01 ~]# cat /etc/named/named.conf.local
zone "DOMAIN.com" {
    type master;
     file "/etc/named/zones/db.DOMAIN.com";
 };

zone "REVERSEIP.in-addr.arpa" {
     type master;
     file "/etc/named/zones/db.REVERSEIP";
};
```

where REVERSEIP would be 1.168.192 if your range would be 192.168.1.0

Then add the Zone:

```
[root@ns01 ~]# cat /etc/named/zones/db.REVERSEIP
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     DOMAIN.com. admin.DOMAIN.com. (
                             23         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
; name servers
      IN      NS      FQDN_NS.com.

; PTR Records
32    IN      PTR     REC1.com.
```

Last entry would be REC1.com reverse lookup ip: 192.168.1.32